# Vim directory content?

Tags: vim

Is there a plugin or something like this that can show directories content in vim.

For example, when you do

```
vim /path/to/dir/
```

and there are another directories inside we have the following structure:

```
../                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
./
dir1/
dir2/
dir3/
```

What I am looking for is something close to this:

```
../                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
./
dir1/
 \_file1
dir2/
 \_file2
dir3/
  \_dir4
      \_file3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are vim plugins for that.
A popular one is e.g.

[NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree).

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to switching to another plugin (like the mentioned *NERDTree*), you can also reconfigure the *netrw* plugin (that ships with Vim and gives you the directory listing) to default to an expandable tree, as per [`:help g:netrw_liststyle`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#g%3Anetrw_liststyle):

```
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
```